# Spectrum of $T$ if $T^2=T$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm having some trouble proving this result:

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T\in L(X)$ be a continuous linear operator such that $T^{2}=T$. Determine the spectrum $\sigma(T)$.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint : Show that the only possible eigenvalues are $0$ and $1$

Comment: This is the definition of a projection.

Comment: @Peter What of the continuous and residual spectrums? It's a good place to start but not the main difficulty in this question in my opinion.

Comment: @amcalde This is true, but not particularly useful to the question.

Comment: My answer to this question can also answer yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117662/if-a3-a-prove-that-ker-lefta-i-rightim-lefta-i-right-v/2117755#2117755.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $0=\sigma(T^2-T)=\sigma(T)^2-\sigma(T)$ where the second equality follows from the spectral mapping theorem and the first equality follows from_______.

Comment: Hamilton-Cayley?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio It follows directly from $T^2-T=0$, no?

Comment: If you take $T= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, then $\sigma(T)^2 - \sigma(T) = \{-1,0,1\}$..

Comment: If $p(x)=x^2-x$, then $p(\sigma(T)) = \{0\}$ and hence $\sigma(T) \subset \{0,1\}$.