# $M^2=I_n$ implies $M$ diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $M$ be an  $n \times n$ matrix  such that
$M^{2}=I_n$; does this imply that $M$ is similar to a diagonal matrix $D$? How can we prove this?

Comment: Since M satisfies $x^2-1=0$,  which has distinct roots, the minimal polynomial will have distinct roots, which implies that M is diagonalizable.

Comment: @Verbe No, the characteristic polynomial won't have distinct roots if $n > 2$.  But the minimal polynomial does, and **that** implies $M$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: You are right, I switched the definitions, apologies!

Comment: For a more general result, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117662/if-a3-a-prove-that-ker-lefta-i-rightim-lefta-i-right-v/2117755#2117755.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Theorem:**
>
> Let $T$ be a linear operator on the finite-dimensional vector space
>   $V$. then $T$ is diagonalizable iff minimal polynomial is of the form
>   $g(t)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(t-\lambda_k), \lambda_j \ne\lambda_k$ for any
>   distict index.

**Solution to the Problem**

Given that $M^2=I.$ Let $g(t)=t^2-1$. We know that $g(M)=0$. Hence it is the minimal polynomial. $g(t)=(t-1)(t+1)$. Hence, $M$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT**: Show that the eigenspaces $\mathbf E(1)$ and $\mathbf E(-1)$ span $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is diagonalisable. Let $W_1$ be the space of generalized eigenvalues for $1$, that is vectors such that $(M-I)^nv=0$ for some $n$. Now note that 
$(M+I)W_1=W_1$ since otherwise there is an element in $W_1$ with eigenvalue $-1$. This implies that $$(M-I)W_1=(M-I)(M+I)W_1=0$$ this all generalized eigenvectors are actual eigenvectors. This implies that algebraic and geometric multiplicities are the same. Hence diagonalizable.

Comment: May I know how ' Now note that $(M+I)W_1=W_1$ since otherwise there is an element in $W_1$ with eigenvalue −1'.  the statement is coming?. $W_1$ is the space of generalised eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue 1 .right?

Comment: Please help me @ReneShipperus

Comment: @ManeeshNarayanan A non surjective linear map on a finite dimensional space, has a non zero kernel.

Comment: I understood the result you mentioned above. How can I apply this here? $v\in W_1, \implies Mv=v, \implies v \in N(M-I).$ How can I relate $W_1$  to $M+I$? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If $v\in F^n$ (where $F$ is the field that you're working with), then$$v=\frac12(v+M.v)+\frac12(v-M.v).$$Since $M^2=\operatorname{Id}$, this expresses $v$ as the sum of a vector $v_1$ such that $M.v_1=v_1$ with a vector $v_{-1}$ such that $M.v_{-1}=-v_{-1}$. So, every vector is sum of eigenvectors and therefore $M$ is diagonalizable.