# $f^2=Id \implies f$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra

I found this in my notes and it seems to me it was given for granted; but when I tried to prove it i couldn't think of anything apart from the fact that, seeing applications as matrices, then $A^2=Id_n$ means that $A$ has all elements on the diagonal equal to $\pm1$; the problem is I wasn't able to prove that that's the only possibility such that $A^2=Id_n$. How could I proceed from here?

Comment: Do you know about the minimal polynomial?

Comment: I know the characteristic polynomial which I believe it's not the same thing you're talking about.

Comment: you need to state the field as this breaks in characteristic 2

Comment: @MartinR not really since in my linear algebra course we haven't seen it yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, for matrices, $A^2 = I$ does not necessarily imply that its diagonal elements are equal to $-1$. Some counterexamples:
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}, \quad A = \frac 13 \pmatrix{1 & -2 & -2\\
-2 & 1 & -2\\ 
-2 & -2 & 1}.
$$
There are several ways to prove that this matrix is necessarily diagonalizable. Since I wasn't able to find an earlier post addressing this problem by searching, here's my favorite. Show that for any vector $v$, the vectors
$$
v_1 = \frac{v + Av}{2}, \quad v_2 = \frac{v - Av}{2}
$$
are eigenvectors of $A$ associated with $1$ and $-1$ respectively. Conclude that every vector $v$ can be decomposed into a sum of eigenvectors with $v = v_1 + v_2$. It follows that $A$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Is the OP's theory that matrices satisfying $A^2=I$ are diagonal matrices having $\pm 1$ on their diagonal correct **if** we look for matrices upto similarity?

Comment: crystal clear, thank you so much!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577343/42969 to me – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24A%5E2%20%3D%20id%24%2C%20AND%20content%3Adiagonalizable)

Comment: @Martin Good find, I might have caught that if I thought to switch A to M