# If $A^3 = A$, prove that $\operatorname{Ker}(A - I) \oplus\operatorname{ Im}(A - I) = V$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I just can't wrap my head around this proof. How to do it? Here is what I tried:

$$A^3 = A$$
$$A^3 - A = 0$$
$$A(A-I)(A+I) = 0$$
Matrix $A$ satisfies the polynomial $p(x)=x(x-1)(x+1)$. Zeroes of $p$ are $-1, 0 ,1$. Minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$ has at least one root, which can only take value  of roots of $p$. Maximum multiplicity of that root in the minimal polynomial is one.

One can then take a look at the eigenspaces that correspond to the specific eigenvalues. What then...? Is that the path that can lead to a solution? Is there a better solution? I don't really get it... Please, be kind and explain this if you can spare the time.

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117662/if-a3-a-prove-that-ker-lefta-i-rightim-lefta-i-right-v) question, but there seems to be a leap of logic in the question, and the accepted answer.

$$A^3 = A$$
doesn't imply $$A^2 = I$$

For instance, take matrix $$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

Also, if we take a linear operator $L:V \to V$, it is obvious that $Ker(L) \cap Im(L) = \{0\}$ ? Do I also need to prove that sum of kernel and image is direct sum?

Comment: Observe that **in any case**, the minimal polynomial of $\;A\;$ is the product of *different* linear polynomials, and thus $\;A\;$ is diagonalizable. Can you take it from here?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ gives an example of a linear operator $L$ with $\operatorname{ker}(L) \cap \operatorname{im}(L) \ne \{ 0 \}$ (since $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is in the intersection).

Comment: No answer in the link you gave says anything remotely similar to this: "$A^3=A$ implies $A^2=I$."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the space is finite dimensional.

Let $y\in \operatorname{Ker}(A-I)\cap \operatorname{Im}(A-I)$, $y=A(x)-x, (A-I)(y)=0$ implies that $(A-I)(A(x)-x)=A^2(x)-2A(x)+x=0$, we deduce that $A^3(x)-2A^2(x)+A(x)=A(x)-2A^2(x)+A(x)=0$. This implies that $A^2(x)=A(x)$,

we replace $A(x)=A^2(x)$ in $A^2(x)-2A(x)+x=0$, we obtain $A(x)-2A(x)+x=x-A(x)=-y=0$

Since $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(A-I)+\dim(\operatorname{Im}(A-I))=\dim(V)$ the result follows.